# Url django with phone number

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i trying match url in django with phone number. First character must is '+' or '0', and all after is number only.
I try like this

`url(r'^verification/(?P<phone_number>[\+|0][0-9]+)/$', views.VerificationView.as_view(),name='verification')`

but this not work.
I tried change to `[\+0-9]` it match '+' but it can in any position.
Can you show me what wrong? Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following url should work:

```
url(r'^verification/(?P<phone_number>[+,0][0-9]+)/$', views.VerificationView.as_view(),name='verification')
```

It will accept both numbers starting with `+` or `0`. Testing reference: https://regexr.com/4cpud.